# Highcharts X-Axis Alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, highcharts

There is an alignment problem as shown in the below pic:
[image]

In the chart, 'Oct 3' point is not on 10/03 as it need to be and it is somewhere between 10/03 and 10/04. It is the case with all the points.

x-axis code is like below:

```
xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            day: '%m/%d'
        },
        formatter: function () {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat("%m/%d", this.value);
        },
        gridLineColor: '#197F07'
    }
```

Same issue is reproduced in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Seenu/wzW2s/):

open the fiddle in IE to see the problem

Comment: I think it's related to your data - probably its 16:34:25 or something like that. Add to tooltip formatter info about hours and minutes at least.

Comment: added fiddle to the question.. http://jsfiddle.net/Seenu/wzW2s/

Comment: Which IE version? In Chrome works fine.

Comment: IE 10.. here is another fiddle with grid lines..http://jsfiddle.net/Seenu/JX2SQ/ open it in IE and chrome to see the difference

Comment: Let's consider: `new Date('2013-10-03T00:00:00').getTime()` - it returns different value in IE10 and Chrome. I thinks it's not related to Highcharts.

Comment: Do you see any possible workaround?

Comment: Two options: change format to another, get timestamp using new `Date(year, month, day ... )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is because if the UTC date format. new Date('2013-10-03T00:00:00').getTime() returns different valuess in IE and Chrome. I suggest you to use timestamps instead of using the UTC format.

personally I prefer timestamp over UTC date format when it comes to datetime axis. with timestamp i think it would be easy to play around with date and functions on it.

```
             data: [
                [1382680330000, 129.9],
                [1382593930000, 71.5],
                [1382536090000, 106.4]
             ]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YYXX8/ is a little demo,

please note that highcharts accepts timestamp in milliseconds

hope this will be useful to you